# How can I make USB tethering stable in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: networking, tethering

Environment: Ubuntu 16.04/AMD Ryzen 5/Asus B350M-A.

After I connect my Android smartphone (happening with LG K220dsz/Micromax MT500) to the desktop PC, there is internet connection, but this repeatedly gets switched off, and the Android folders mount instead.

Network shows: Wired Connection 1.

How can I make the usb tethering connection stable?

```
5 10:17:39 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Providers.UbuntuGeoIP[1547]: ** (ubuntu-geoip-provider:1862): WARNING **: Unable to connect to geoip service, status: 2
    Nov  5 10:21:39 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Providers.UbuntuGeoIP[1547]: ** (ubuntu-geoip-provider:1862): WARNING **: Unable to connect to geoip service, status: 2
    Nov  5 10:21:58 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT smartd[1012]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate changed from 96 to 97
    Nov  5 10:21:58 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT smartd[1012]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered changed from 91 to 90
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2106.268549] cdc_acm 5-1:1.3: urb 11 failed submission with -19
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2106.268559] usb 5-1: USB disconnect, device number 10
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2106.268623] cdc_acm 5-1:1.3: urb 12 failed submission with -19
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2106.268710] cdc_acm 5-1:1.3: urb 13 failed submission with -19
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2106.268721] rndis_host 5-1:1.0 enp40s0f3u1: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:28:00.3-1, RNDIS device
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2106.268783] cdc_acm 5-1:1.3: urb 14 failed submission with -19
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2106.268825] cdc_acm 5-1:1.3: urb 15 failed submission with -19
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2106.268903] cdc_acm 5-1:1.3: urb 0 failed submission with -19
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2106.268985] cdc_acm 5-1:1.3: urb 1 failed submission with -19
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2106.269073] cdc_acm 5-1:1.3: urb 2 failed submission with -19
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2106.269144] cdc_acm 5-1:1.3: urb 3 failed submission with -19
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2106.269224] cdc_acm 5-1:1.3: urb 4 failed submission with -19
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2106.269304] cdc_acm 5-1:1.3: urb 5 failed submission with -19
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2106.269384] cdc_acm 5-1:1.3: urb 6 failed submission with -19
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2106.269465] cdc_acm 5-1:1.3: urb 7 failed submission with -19
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2106.269548] cdc_acm 5-1:1.3: urb 8 failed submission with -19
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2106.269628] cdc_acm 5-1:1.3: urb 9 failed submission with -19
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2106.269704] cdc_acm 5-1:1.3: urb 10 failed submission with -19
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT NetworkManager[3243]: <info>  [1509857521.7920] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:28:00.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/net/enp40s0f3u1, iface: enp40s0f3u1)
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT ModemManager[2957]: <info>  (net/enp40s0f3u1): released by modem /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:28:00.3/usb5/5-1
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2106.299947] cdc_acm 5-1:1.2: failed to set dtr/rts
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT ModemManager[2957]: <info>  (tty/ttyACM0): released by modem /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:28:00.3/usb5/5-1
    Nov  5 10:22:01 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT NetworkManager[3243]: <info>  [1509857521.8224] device (ttyACM0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'removed') [20 10 36]
    Nov  5 10:22:22 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2126.607945] usb 5-1: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
    Nov  5 10:22:22 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2126.748408] usb 5-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1004, idProduct=631c
    Nov  5 10:22:22 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2126.748411] usb 5-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
    Nov  5 10:22:22 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2126.748413] usb 5-1: Product: LGE Android Phone
    Nov  5 10:22:22 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2126.748414] usb 5-1: Manufacturer: LGE
    Nov  5 10:22:22 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2126.748416] usb 5-1: SerialNumber: LGK2204SN7IB99
    Nov  5 10:22:22 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor[1547]: (process:1908): GVFS-GPhoto2-WARNING **: device (null) has no BUSNUM property, ignoring
    Nov  5 10:23:41 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2206.247087] usb 5-1: USB disconnect, device number 11
    Nov  5 10:23:42 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2206.583588] usb 5-1: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
    Nov  5 10:23:42 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2206.724439] usb 5-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1004, idProduct=6344
    Nov  5 10:23:42 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2206.724442] usb 5-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
    Nov  5 10:23:42 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2206.724444] usb 5-1: Product: LGE Android Phone
    Nov  5 10:23:42 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2206.724446] usb 5-1: Manufacturer: LGE
    Nov  5 10:23:42 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2206.724448] usb 5-1: SerialNumber: LGK2204SN7IB99
    Nov  5 10:23:42 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT NetworkManager[3243]: <warn>  [1509857622.2702] device (usb0): failed to find device 6 'usb0' with udev
    Nov  5 10:23:42 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT NetworkManager[3243]: <info>  [1509857622.2715] manager: (usb0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
    Nov  5 10:23:42 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2206.751500] rndis_host 5-1:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:28:00.3-1, RNDIS device, 26:44:16:da:5b:9c
    Nov  5 10:23:42 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2206.752000] cdc_acm 5-1:1.2: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
    Nov  5 10:23:42 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT mtp-probe: checking bus 5, device 12: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:28:00.3/usb5/5-1"
    Nov  5 10:23:42 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT mtp-probe: bus: 5, device: 12 was not an MTP device
    Nov  5 10:23:42 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT kernel: [ 2206.764419] rndis_host 5-1:1.0 enp40s0f3u1: renamed from usb0
    Nov  5 10:23:42 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT NetworkManager[3243]: <info>  [1509857622.2980] device (usb0): interface index 6 renamed iface from 'usb0' to 'enp40s0f3u1'
    Nov  5 10:23:42 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT NetworkManager[3243]: <info>  [1509857622.3022] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:28:00.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/net/enp40s0f3u1, iface: enp40s0f3u1)
    Nov  5 10:23:42 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT NetworkManager[3243]: <info>  [1509857622.3023] device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:28:00.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/net/enp40s0f3u1, iface: enp40s0f3u1): no ifupdown configuration found.
    Nov  5 10:23:42 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT NetworkManager[3243]: <info>  [1509857622.3025] device (enp40s0f3u1): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
    Nov  5 10:23:42 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT NetworkManager[3243]: <info>  [1509857622.3031] device (enp40s0f3u1): link connected
    Nov  5 10:23:42 Gulshan-Sukhobristi-AA3-NT NetworkManager[3243]: <info>  [1509857622.3041] device (enp40s0f3u1): reset MAC address to 26:44:16:DA:5B:9C
```

Comment: I have edited my question with all the details known to me.

Comment: I have researched through all similiar USB tethering issues; implemented all commands, but it is still unstable. Commands I used: sudo systemctl stop/disable modem manager; edit NetConf file in etc folder; synaptic manager shows modeswitch installed, cant recall whether manually/automatic.

Comment: I have again edited my heading and post for the specific question.

Comment: This sounds like a mechanical or electrical issue that disconnects and shortly thereafter reconnects the USB client device. Either that or the USB chipset or stack of the client device is faulty, neither of which are related to Ubuntu and therefore off topic here.